# How do you partition sequential point data in Java into equal size groups

Tags: java, data-structures

I would like to know a way of partitioning a set of sequential points into equal sized groups of points (groups have fixed size) e.g for instance group size could be 4 where each group would have 4 points

I am then looking to process points in each group a group at a time

My aim is to eventually remove a point from each group based on a constraint

Also any idea of which data structure would be best recommended for the partitioning task

Comment: By "sequential" do you mean it is in a `List`?

Comment: Hi Andy yes. At the moment I have been using arraylist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can partition into a list-of-lists by using `List.subList`:

```
List<List<T>> listOfLists = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i += partitionSize) {
  listOfLists.add(list.subList(i, Math.min(i + partitionSize, list.size());
}
```

Note that the elements of `listOfLists` are views into `list`.